# Regex Python except a sequence of letters

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

Sorry to bother because I know this topic already exists, but after a lots of tries I still couldn't arrive the the result I want.

My code:

```
string1 = 'James CameronSteven Spielberg'
string2 = 'Martin Scorsese'
string3 = 'John McQueen'

result1= re.split("(?=[a-zéè])(?=[A-ZÉÈÊ])", string1) # ['James Cameron','Steven Spielberg']
result2= re.split("(?=[a-zéè])(?=[A-ZÉÈÊ])", string2) # ['Martin Scorsese']
result3= re.split("(?=[a-zéè])(?=[A-ZÉÈÊ])", string3) # ['John Mc', 'Queen']
```

I'm trying to add an exception to my regex (it's a loop so I want to only use one regex), so I can except all names started with "Mc"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?<=[a-zéè])(?<!Mc)(?=[A-ZÉÈÊ])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9pbNzK/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=[a-zéè])` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `a-z` and `é` and `è` letters
- `(?<!Mc)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is `Mc` immediately to the left of the current position
- `(?=[A-ZÉÈÊ])`  - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with uppercase ASCII letters or `É`, `È`, or `Ê` letter.